# Group pages without affecting the router - Nuxt.js

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js

I am using Nuxt to create my application and I have a group of pages that are related in a way.

So I will simplify things a bit but my current structure looks like this

```
/pages
  /login
  /registration
  /forgot-password
  /resend-confirmation-email
  .
  .
  .
```

This folder structure is creating `/login`, `/registration`, `/forgot-password`, `/resend-confirmation-email` routes, which is cool.

So, in a way I can group first four pages to a group and name it `authorization`.

Ideally new folder structure should look like

```
/pages
   /authorization
     /login
     /registration
     /forgot-password
     /resend-confirmation-email
  .
  .
  .
```

However what I would like is for the router to not get messed up, I would very much like for those routes to remain the way they were.

Is that possible?

Comment: What about `alias` and `redirect` options? `alias` will better fit here - https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/redirect-and-alias.html#redirect

Comment: uhm, not sure how will this help me... If I was using vue-router directly I would have known how to do this. But nuxt is creating router file based on directory structure and I'd like to override that....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So with no plugins and stuff, what I did was replacing the folder name from route object in extend routes function.

File `nuxt.config.js`

```
router: {
    extendRoutes(nuxtRoutes) {
      nuxtRoutes.map(route => {
        route.path = route.path.replace('/authorization', '');
        route.name = route.name.replace('authorization-', '');

        return route;
      });
    },
    ....
}
```

This looks like a hack to me, but it actually does exactly what I want. For some larger projects I might consider fully overriding the router but this is kinda okay for now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use nuxt router extras module
https://github.com/alibaba-aero/nuxt-router-extras/blob/dev/README.md

```
<router>
    path: /posts
</router>
```

Comment: I will try this. I am using nuxt-i18n module as well in order to translate my route names (for the sake of SEO) so I will see how this gets along with it..

Answer (score 1):

### **For Nuxt3, use `definePageMeta`**

In Nuxt3 use [definePageMeta](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/utils/define-page-meta#definepagemeta) to set route aliases.

**1. Make your pages**

Make the page files and group them logically in a sub-folder as you would for general organization.

```
pages/auth/
            login.vue
            logout.vue
            register.vue
            forgot.vue
            //etc...

            index.vue // not necessary, but a nice convenience page
```

At this point your routes are as accessible as such:

```
www.website.com/auth/login
www.website.com/auth/logout
www.website.com/auth/register
www.website.com/auth/forgot

www.website.com/auth   // accessible if index.vue exists; maybe a nice convenience page showing auth state and shortcuts
```

**2. Setup alias routes**

With working operation of regular pages and routes, now create additional specific alias routes you'd want.

Example: `www.website.com/login` would be a nice convenient URL.

Set a route alias to make it work:

**pages/auth/login.vue**

```
definePageMeta({
  alias: '/login'
})
```

Now you have two operational routes rendering `pages/auth/login.vue`:
`www.website.com/auth/login` - The original file-based route Nuxt creates
`www.website.com/login` - The alias route you created

If you want more thorough overriding of Nuxt's page-based routing, look at Custom Routing docs: https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/going-further/custom-routing